# Задать один и тот же id для label и checkbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть такой код:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsTaskDone, new { id = item.Id, @class = "isdone" })
```

Как мне с помощью Razor сгенерировать Label с таким же Id?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте типовое приложение, которое генерится студией и посмотрите код, например:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот собственно, вам и label и поле. Если посмотрите разметку -- увидите, что всё генерируется логично и правильно.

Это немного не то, что сделали вы: вы жёстко задали id, он у вас собственный, но я рекомендую так и не делать, если вам безразлично, какой это id.

Главное, что есть связка между лейблом и полем, она автоматическая -- ну и хорошо.

Возможно, что вам вот позарез нужно свой собственный id жёстко зашить (не рекомендовал бы, но может вы решили жёстко завязться на конкретные ID из-за собственных скриптов), тогда вам ничего не мешает точно также жестко передать в label id, как вы и класс передаёте.

Излишний контроль и жёсткость -- это нехорошо: нужно на это тратить время, усилия... Можно обойтись без излишнего контроля -- ну и не прописывайте всё слишком подробно, пусть фреймворк сам сделает.

Comment: Я хочу кастомизировать чекбокс,для этого мне надо в label указать id чекбокса.
Поэтому я хочу сделать для чекбокса и лейбла один Id